# how to efficiently get all the user_likes from one feed's comments with graph api or fql

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I'm getting one feed and all his comments,
I query each comment id with :
170169929672639_320612368034130_1646407?fields=user_likes,
to know if the current user likes the comment.

Is there a way to get all feed\comments (well not ALL, but the next group of comments)
with the user_like field for each comment in one request (batch request/multy query fql/other)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field expansion update to the Graph API will let you get all the likes for all comments on a feed - USER_ID?fields=name,feed.fields(comments.fields(likes)). 
Link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/

Comment: Hi :)

Just came to answer my own question after I saw the field expansion update.


And after playing with it, It also works without field expansion.


just small note, the like field of the comment is user_likes.


I use it like this and it gets all likes of the current user for each comment in the feed :


FEEDID/comments?user_likes&limit=30

Thanks.

Comment: OR :
FEEDID?fields=comments.fields(id,from,message,user_likes)